# Missing null or zero values metrics from Google analytics reporting api

Tags: google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I was extracting raw data using Google analytics reporting api using a java code. Extracting full data fetched from the query using the pagetoken. The below metrics and dimensions are used -

Metric
1. ga:searchExitRate
2. ga:searchUniques
3. ga:avgSearchResults

Dimension
1.ga:date
2.ga:searchKeyword
3.ga:deviceCategory

When I used the same query in query explorer for the same date range I get 28924 records . When I ran my code it is giving me null point exception after 20000 records and it seems ga:searchExitRate does not have same number of rows as the other metric for the same combination of dimension. But when check in query explorer it is giving me perfect reaponse matching the row count.

I am using 3 report request (each with one metric and required combination of dimension) from my java program and adding them together and then reading the response for the same combination of dimensions.

Is there any way to address this ? Is it a best practice to query a single metric always while fetching raw data from ga ?

As per my requirement i need to store 5-6 metrics together with a fixed set of dimension for reporting in tableau.
Please help.

Comment: Which methods did you use, which documentation try-it did you test? Maybe show some relevant code also?